# Answers all, boob, X

Tags: riddle, mathematics, word, calculation-puzzle

A four-letter name is encoded A=0 to Z=25. Find a name that satisfies:

> The sum of the integers answers all,
> their product is like a boob,
> and their range is X.

Order the integers by increasing length of their English spelling. If equal length, then alphabetically.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> ELON

The numbers being

> 4, 11, 14, 13

Their sum being

> 42 the answer to life, the universe and everything per THHGTTG

Their product being

> 8008 which reads BOOB on a calculator

Their range being

> 10 per the Roman numeral X

The solution was found

> By factoring 8008 as $2^3\cdot7\cdot11\cdot 13$ and then finding the only factorisation into 4 numbers with a range of 10.